# Jqgrid - Multiselectected rows no longer persist after triggering a JqGrid reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a multi-selected Jqgrid. Initially on loading the grid with the Json reponse from the server, the multiselected rows persist correctly as I navigate from one page to another.

The ids of the rows selected are stored in an Array and this Array is updated on paging. I use this array to check the already selected rows on returning back to the page. Sorting works fine and I faced no problem so far.

On applying a filter on a particular field, a request is sent to the server which returns the new filtered result in Json and then reloads the grid with it.

The first page is rendered correctly with the selected rows checked but on changing the page and returning back the rows are no longer selected. However the array still contains the ids and is also containing the new added ids.

How is that the Multiselected feature stops working after a reload??? Or is it not even because of the reload??

Here is the code:

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
var selectedFieldsMap={};
var selectedFieldsObjs = [];
var selectedFieldIds = [];
$(function() {
    //function called when applying a filter
    $('#ApplyFilterBtn').click(function() {
            saveGridState();
        $('#Grid').setGridParam({ url: getUrl() });
        $('#Grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
    });
});

function saveGridState() {
       var selectedIds = $('#Grid').getGridParam('selarrrow');
       $('#Grid').data(current_page, selectedIds);
       _.each(selectedIds, function(id) {
                selectedFieldIds.push(id);
            });
       var idsToBeAdded = _.difference(selectedIds, getExistingRowIdsForGrid('#list'));
       selectedFieldsMap[current_page] = idsToBeAdded;
       _.each(idsToBeAdded, function(id) {
       selectedFieldsObjs.push($('#Grid').getRowData(id));
                   });
}

function getExistingRowIdsForGrid(gridSelector) {
var existingFields = $(gridSelector).getRowData();
return  _.map(existingFields, function(obj) { return obj.Id; });    

function resetFilterValuesAndReloadGrid() {
    //reset filters and set grid param
    $('#Grid').setGridParam({
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        page: 1,
        url: getUrl()
    });
    $('#Grid').jqGrid('sortGrid', 'Id', true);
    $("#Grid").trigger('reloadGrid');
}

    $("#Grid").jqGrid({
        url: getUrl(),
        datatype: "json",
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        height: 330,
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Type', 'Category'],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "DataRoot",
            page: "CurrentPage",
            total: "TotalPages",
            records: "TotalRecords",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "",
            id: "0"
        },
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 95, align: 'center', sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'Type', index: 'ValueTypeName', width: 110, align: 'left',sortable: true },
            { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 72, align: 'left', sortable: true },
        ],

        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: pageCount[0],
        rowList: pageCount,
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        multiselect: true,

        loadComplete: function () {
            if(selectedFieldIds) {   
         $.each(_.uniq(selectedFieldIds), function(index, value) {
                    $('#Grid').setSelection(value, true);
                });
            }
        } ,

        onPaging : function () {
            saveGridState();
        },

        loadBeforeSend: function() {
            current_page = $(this).getGridParam('page').toString();

        } ,
        onSortCol: function () {
            saveGridState();
        }
    });

}

function getUrl() {
//return url with the parameters and filtering
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you post any of your code, to show what you are doing?

Comment: Hey @JustinEthier Sorry for the late reply. I have updated the question with the code..

Comment: No worries, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, what happens is on reload of the grid the function which checks the row is called as it is in the document.ready()and the on grid loadComplete the same function is called. Toggle happens and the selection is removed. I've added an if condition to see if the grid is selected or not.

```
 loadComplete: function () {
            var selRowIds = jQuery('#Grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
            if (selRowIds.length > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var $this = $(this), i, count;
                for (i = 0, count = idsOfSelectedRows.length; i < count; i++) {
                    $this.jqGrid('setSelection', idsOfSelectedRows[i], false);
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1, glad you were able to solve your problem! When you have a chance, please mark this as the accepted answer (you may have to wait a day), so everyone else knows you have a fix.